# How do I use google translate api to do a 'literal' translation instead of a meaningful translation?

Tags: google-translate

How do I use google translate api to do a 'literal' translation instead of a meaningful translation? I am using REST API call for translate provided by google cloud platform.

For e.g. 
Text to be translated - 'गुलाब' 
Result expected using API - 'gulab' 
Currently it gives result as - 'rose'

Comment: I already answered a [really similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837371/google-translate-rest-api-getting-the-nouns-adjective-ect/49881953#49881953). You can read (and up-vote) the answer there. I suggest you to "star" the feature request mentioned.